# Why PublishSubject does not emit first element

Tags: android, rx-java

I try to use rx and `PublishSubject`. So I create object:

`PublishSubject<MyEvent> events = PublishSubject.create();`

and in my service I put `MyEvent` in that.

`events.onNext(new MyEvent);`

So sometimes I don't receive the first event, but the second I receive.
And sometimes I receive all events. Can anybody explain, what problem can be here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PublishSubject` emits the event to all "currently subscribed" subscribers. It does not emit to subscribers that subscribe in the future.

`BehaviorSubject` will emit the last known value when subscribed to, then behave like a `PublishSubject`. My guess is that this is the behavior you expect.

Comment: I subscribe on my events in `onCreate` of my service

Comment: Be aware that RxJava by default is not thread-safe, if you're emitting events from multiple asynchronous sources, you need to wrap the Subject into a `SerializedSubject` to keep it thread-safe.

Comment: If you have any asynchrony, there is no real guarantee on the ordering of events versus subscriptions unless you do explicit `subscribe()` followed by `onNext()`. `BehaviorSubject` is the way to go for these kinds of things.